# NSFW Website loaded on home network then open at work

Tags: network, ssh, chrome

I use my personal laptop at work. Yesterday evening I had a NSFW website open and didnt close the tab in Chrome. At work, I connected to my works network and then immediately closed the tab without reloading or clicking any links on the page. Will my work know which page I visited?

Note, my work has never installed anything onto my machine.

Comment: it depends on the site which you were using.

Comment: It's quite likely that the website sent some requests in the background (e.g. ajax)

Comment: The site was Pornhub. Com

Comment: Actually a typical website does not connect a single web server. It has several advertise which uses different server. As it is NSFW site, its advertise also quite same. Even if the site itself stops sending data, iFrames (adds) may have send data when you was at work.

Comment: This is a far more specific version of that same question, and I think it merits its own post. This post lends itself to a demonstration of how to analyze a websites network traffic. The generic post is a policy and network implementation question, first and foremost.

Comment: a lot of site/ad JS does stuff when internet connectivity is restored, so quite possibly. It might hit just weird ad urls and not pornhub.com though. you can re-create it and use devtools ([F12]) to see what your specific page does when internet returns after an absence.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what perimeter security your employer has. As you stated there is nothing on your laptop so the only way that the employer could catch this is if there is a firewall or other device at the perimeter tracking all traffic.

If there is such a device it will likely record how much traffic you passed between your machine and that site. This gives you some leverage. You can explain to your employer the situation and the tiny amount of data passed will back that up.

All that being said, it is highly unlikely your scenario triggered any alarms with your security team and I would not worry about it.